# find label in position pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5, label, position

I am planning my code, and I will use PyQt5.
I want to have several labels contained inside a widget, in various positions.
I then want to check if, given a set of coordinates, a label exists at these coordinates.
Is there a way of checking this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly why do you need this and the scenario that requires you to find a specific object at the given coordinates?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am planning a maze game that needs to be implemented in PyQt.I was planning of building it as a set of square labels (of 24px of width) that could be either black (walls) or white (walkable pathway). I want to check when the user presses, for instance, the right arrow on the keyboard, if there is a label at 24 px on the right of the current label, and, if so, if it is black or white.

Comment: In that case trying to get the widget based on the coordinates doesn't seem a good option. Are those squares placed in a grid, and do those squares fill the whole grid?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, they are in a grid and they fill the whole grid

Comment: If your player moves around at fixed steps (you mentioned 24px, so I'm assuming that the movement is fixed), then there's no need to think in pixel coordinates: when you create the grid, keep a reference of the tiles (a simple list of lists of bools, for instance), then track the position of the player and the tiles next to it by using row/column coordinates. It's more reliable than using widget coordinates, is conceptually more simple, and makes further implementation much easier.

Comment: That said, just for reference, there *is* a way to know the widget at specific coordinates: [`QApplication.widgetAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#widgetAt); but it's only used for very specific and rare situations, which is not your case, as it is *not* reliable for what you need, and has more drawbacks than benefits.

Comment: That's great, thank you for your help!